# How to implement bilinear interpolation?

Tags: python, numpy, affinetransform, bilinear-interpolation

I'm trying to implement bilinear interpolation to an image after affine transformation (using `numpy` only), and I don't understand how to implement ?

I know how to use nearest neighbor interpolation (easy):

```
X = np.round(coords[0,:])
Y = np.round(coords[1,:])
```

but I don't know how to use bilinear interpolation instead.

I could use some help, thanks :)

Comment: check the wikipedia, it has explicit formulas for this

Comment: I'm familiar with the formula, I just don't understand how to use it in my implementation. I'll be more specific - how do I implement bilinear similar way I implemented NN?